# neat way to implement a jquery custom filter (selecting based on parent's class)?

Tags: jquery

I want to select every textarea that **does not** have a DIV with class *red* among its parents, do something to each, and then do **something else** with the rest of textareas on the page. In other words, select a set of elements, work on only some of them, and then do something else with the rest.

I know I can do something like below, but is there a less clumsy way of doing it?

```
$('textarea').filter(function() {
    return $(this).parents("div.red").length > 0;
}).css('border','1px solid red').end().filter(function() {
    return $(this).parents("div.red").length == 0;
}).css('border','1px solid green');
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What's wrong with this way?  jQuery is powerful, but there is something to be said for keeping code clean and readable and not trying to be too clever.

```
$('textarea').each(function() {
  if ($(this).parent('div.red').length > 0) {
    $(this).css('border', 'solid 1px red');
  } else {
    $(this).css('border', 'solid 1px green');
  }
}
```

Comment: Nothing, really. I guess I was so entangled in the jQuery way of doing things and "trying to be clever", that I forgot that what's happening behind the scenes is essentially this..

Answer (score 5):

maybe not the most efficient, but fairly intuitive is

```
$('textarea').css('border', '1px solid green');
$('div.red textarea').css('border', '1px solid red');
```

although something like this may belong more in css if you are trying to apply it to every textarea at all times:

```
textarea {
    border: 1px solid green;
}

div.red textarea {
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Edit:

As Paolo Bergantino mentions, if you want to do something more complex than one css command on the textareas you can use

```
var redAreas = $('div.red textarea');
var otherAreas = $('textarea').not(redAreas);
```

Comment: I think your green/red logic might be backwards from the OPs

Comment: This works because of the way CSS cascades, but I am not sure if this answers the OP's question - I was under the impression the CSS was just an example and he wants to do something else to the two different set of elements.

Comment: Yes, my question is about having a subset of a set of elements, and then being able to get just the remaining elements of that very same set (subset2 = set - subset). Sorry if the wording is not sufficiently clear.

Answer (score 2):

```
$("textarea").not("div.Red textarea"); /* textareas which do not have a div with class Red among its parents */
$("div.Red textarea"); /* textareas which have a div with class Red amoung its parents */
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if its any better, but you could try.

```
$('textarea').each(function() {
  var borderColor = $(this).parents('div.red').length > 0 ? 'red' : 'green';
  $(this).css('border', '1px solid ' + borderColor);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

What is wrong with just using CSS?

```
textarea 
{
    border: 1px solid green;
}

div.red textarea 
{
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```